# Which Actions on Google features doesn't dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs support?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

In the readme it says

> If you are only interested in building Dialogflow fulfillment for the Google Assistant and don't plan on using other integrations, please use the Actions on Google NPM module (actions-on-google) which supports all Actions on Google features.

Could anyone provide some info on what features we would miss out on if we use dialogflow-fulfillment-nodejs instead of the actions-on-google one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many features that are part of the Actions on Google platform which are not available more generally to other platforms, necessitating the creation of a separate library.

- [Transactions](https://developers.google.com/actions/transactions/)
- [User storage](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data)
- [Daily updates](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/daily) and [notifications](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/updates/notifications)
- Quick [Google Sign-In](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in)
- [Permissions](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers) to get things like user location
- [Deep-linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/helpers) into an Android app
- The ability to check [surface capabilities](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/surface-capabilities) and move the conversation to a new surface

And [many more advanced features](https://developers.google.com/actions/extending-the-assistant)